# Keep running the iOS app on background, collecting data from accelerator and send it to server

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process

I've developed an app, for reading the Accelerator data, store them locally and send them frequently with a specific interval to a server. The app must work on background, but after a while ( 3 minutes sometime ) it stops sending like it's closed.

Is it possible to keep the app alive all the time, running and sending data to a server on background? how ?

The app is supposed to keep working for weeks.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iOS will allow you 3 minutes of execution in background.
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

If you want to keep running there are various "workarounds" but not a stable solution.You can initiate background tasks and then manage them

```
 -(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

{ 
  UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;

    backgroundTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self              selector:@selector(backgroundTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
   [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
 }];

}
```

Comment: But some applications like Viber or Whatsapp are running all the time.

Comment: You can use apple push notification service to wake application and do work in background.

Comment: I tried the above solution (Using Timer), and I added

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

in backgroundTask method, but still after a while ( more than 3 minutes ) it stops updating location and basically app stops on background. Any idea how it happens ?

Comment: You need more work than that.
 You can use some help from this link:
http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7

If you find it helpful accept :D